# Obtaining Private Prospectuses

Tags: private-company, research

I am interested in obtaining business model information about private companies.  Specifically, I would like to know about things like, areas of growth, short falls, challenges and guidance.

How can I get quarterly information about private companies?

Comment: The benefit of being a private company is that there is no need to share such information.  You can ask them, but they will likely tell you to go away.

Comment: @PeteB. that should be an answer not a comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I get quarterly information about private companies?

Ask the owner(s).  Unelss you have a relationship and they're interested in helping you, they will likely tell you no as there's no compelling reason for them to do so.  It's a huge benefit of not taking a company public.